# Activity not found Exception with Hyperlink

Tags: android

Today I came thorugh a strange problem. I am trying to set a HTML content to my textview and which has some hyperlinks in it. When I click on a particlar link the app crashes and the error I get is,

**08-21 06:00:44.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8362): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=#enlarge-map (has extras) }**

Could anyone explain me what this is and how to get over it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use TextView hyperlink, your link should include protocol (e.g. http://www.stackoverflow.com).

I guess that your hyperlink is hash tag `#enlarge-map`, in this case you should use WebView instead.

Comment: Ya, I tried this already. But I get this error, "webpage not available" in the webview. That is the reason I am trying this.